# How to use escapeinside from minted in an external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted, shell-escape

I have managed to do the following

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}

%----create design
\newcommand\circled[3]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, text width=8pt, align=center]
            (char) {\textcolor{#2}{\sffamily\bfseries\scriptsize #3}};
    }%
}

\newcommand\lstnote[1]{
    \kern 1.5em
    \circled{purple}{pink!50!white}{#1} % ----> edited
}
%------
\newmintedfile[vbcode]{vb.net}{xleftmargin=20pt,linenos=true,linenos,escapeinside = <>}

\begin{document}
Example code
\vbcode{code.vb}
\end{document}
```

--
**code file --> code.vb**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        '==================================
        'example code
        '==================================
        <\lstnote{1}>Dim entrada1 As String
        <\lstnote{2}>Dim entrada2 As String

        <\lstnote{3}>Console.WriteLine("Write to ")
        <\lstnote{4}>entrada1 = Console.ReadLine
        <\lstnote{5}>Console.Write("Find Write > ")
        <\lstnote{6}>entrada2 = Console.Read

    End Sub

End Module
```

> Result
>   [image: reference]

--

> Can you tell me what I failed?

**error obtained**

```latex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.8 ...entrada1} \PYG{o+ow}{As} \PYG{k+kt}{String}
```

Comment: According to the documentation you can only use a single escape opening and closing character. So e.g. `escapeinside=<>` should work.

Comment: @siracusa ok, but not working

Comment: @siracusa, edited, thank you for your observation, but still the error follows

Comment: Have you tried deleting all auxiliary files before recompiling? Your latest version compiles for me without error, though the result is still wrong. This may be due to an outdated `pygments` version on my system, and I don't know Python well enough to debug this any further.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted and I get the same error